# How to go directly to the App Store by clicking on the dynamic link when the user has not installed the application?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

Currently, Dynamic Link is used normally in the React-native app. However, the Dynamic Link is not redirected to the app-store when the user has not installed the app.

```
createShortDynamicLink(contentKey, title, subtitle, youTubeVideoId) {
  const dynamicLinkDomain = __DEV__
    ? 'test.page.link'
    : 'test.page.link';

  const link =
    new firebase.links.DynamicLink(`https://test.com/contents/${contentKey}`, dynamicLinkDomain)
      .social.setImageUrl(`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${youTubeVideoId}/hqdefault.jpg`) // make size over 200*200
      .social.setDescriptionText(subtitle)
      .social.setTitle(title)
      .android.setPackageName(DeviceInfo.getBundleId())
      .ios.setBundleId(DeviceInfo.getBundleId());

  return firebase.links()
    .createShortDynamicLink(link, 'UNGUESSABLE');
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/web-to-app
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/links/reference/SocialParameters
I used this docs..

Comment: I'd look at providers who do this for you like branch.io.  All the details of making it work in Android links, Chrome links, and iOS links is a pain.

Comment: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/links/reference/IOSParameters <- Need to setFallbackUrl setting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set fallback links. You can find more options about properties in [official page.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create)

Comment: thanks! https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/links/reference/IOSParameters <- this Docs helps me!